# DatePickerDialog is not working in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this problem when adding the DataPickerDialog, the project structure is the drawer layout example of android studio.

```
package asaek.ikusi.ikusi_1.ui.home
import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import asaek.ikusi.ikusi_1.MainActivity
import asaek.ikusi.ikusi_1.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class HomeFragment : Fragment(){

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textVFecha: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.textView_Fecha)
        val textVHora: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.textView_Hora)
        val textVFecha_Atencion: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.textView_Fecha_atencion)

        textVFecha_Atencion.setOnClickListener {
            val c = Calendar.getInstance()
            val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            val pickDate = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{ view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                //Asignandole al textview
                textVFecha_Atencion.setText("" + dayOfMonth + " - " + (monthOfYear+1) + " - " + year)
            }, year, month, day)
            pickDate.show()
        }

        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
        val timeFormat = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault())

        val fechaActual = dateFormat.format(Date())
        val horaActual = timeFormat.format(Date())

        textVFecha.setText(fechaActual)
        textVHora.setText(horaActual)
        return root
    }
}
```

The error throws it in "This" and throws me the following "Type mismatch: inferred type is HomeFragment but Context was expected"

```
    val pickDate = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{ view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, Asael.

`this` in that place/context, refers to the `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` instance, because that's where you are in the execution point; what you need is a `Context`, and specifically a context that can drive a Theme (like a Fragment or Activity context) so your Dialog matches your theme. `OnDateSetListener` is not a context...

Change it to, for example:

`val pickDate = DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener...`

#### Where does requireContext() come from?

It comes from the `Fragment` class:

```
    /**
     * Return the {@link Context} this fragment is currently associated with.
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if not currently associated with a context.
     * @see #getContext()
     */
    @NonNull
    public final Context requireContext() {
        Context context = getContext();
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to a context.");
        }
        return context;
    }
```

#### How can the `DateSetListener` access the method from the Fragment?

That's a tricky one, but your `DateSetListener()` is an anonymous instance of the class `DateSetListener`, and anonymous classes in java, have direct access to the parent/containing class. That's why you can call `requireContext()` from your anonymous class, contained in a `Fragment`.

If you were to copy and paste your code to another class, a class that is not a Fragment, you'd get a compilation error (unless your `another` class has a `requireContext()` method, that is.

:)